# Changing CloudQueueMessage type leads to Exception binding parameter 'myQueueItem'. mscorlib: String reference not set to an instance of a String

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

When creating a new `QueueTrigger` Azure function, I'd like to switch the `string` input to a `CloudQueueMessage`.

I have changed the signature to:

`public async static Task Run([QueueTrigger("%queue-name%", Connection = "AzureStorageConnection")]CloudQueueMessage myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)`

I get the error below:

`8/15/17 12:16:07 AM] Function started (Id=a137d868-1256-4a67-a225-8a95fb0e31fb)
[8/15/17 12:16:07 AM] Executing 'TokenRefresh' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'refreshtoken'.', Id=a137d868-1256-4a67-a225-8a95fb0e31fb)
[8/15/17 12:16:07 AM] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[8/15/17 12:16:07 AM] Exception while executing function: TokenRefresh. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'myQueueItem'. mscorlib: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
[8/15/17 12:16:07 AM] Parameter name: s.`

The function app is correctly popping items and then then because it is then throwing rapid exceptions all items in that queue go to the poison queue. I'm using the latest functions sdk and windows azure sdk nuget packages.

Comment: Are you using the VS2017 preview tooling? Could you share the generate `function.json` file for this functions?

Comment: You need to add the dependency of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue` in your function it will work

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I checked this issue on Azure portal. I found it could work, and here is the code snippet under my `run.csx` file as follows:

```html
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;

[FunctionName("QueueTriggerCSharp")]
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]CloudQueueMessage myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem.AsString}");
}
```

**Result:**

> 2017-08-15T07:35:27.104 Function started (Id=0ed03b74-bc9c-408a-9607-55e2942f1d50)
>
> 2017-08-15T07:35:27.214 **C# Queue trigger function processed: sample queue data**
>
> 2017-08-15T07:35:27.214 Function completed (Success, Id=0ed03b74-bc9c-408a-9607-55e2942f1d50, Duration=108ms)

As garth mason mentioned, then I checked it on my local side by using VS 2017 function class library. Also, I found a similar issue [How to change the parameters types using a queue trigger and a VS 2017 function class library](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d083c251-1654-4ecb-b922-45f28bdbd0e6/how-to-change-the-parameters-types-using-a-queue-trigger-and-a-vs-2017-function-class-library?forum=AzureFunctions) and this [git issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1616), you could refer to them for solving this issue.

Comment: Thank you, this is true, see my answer above though that what it turned out to be was a dependency mismatch on `Windows.AzureStorage` lib. Unfortunately, this is going to be showstopper for our migration to Functions.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this was a result of trying to use `Windows.AzureStorage` `v8.2.1` instead of the `v7.2.1` which is binding redirected. Since the `CloudQueueMessage` object is a mismatch between versions, you have to use the dependencies that Functions runtime depends on.

Confirmed by Functions PM:
https://twitter.com/lindydonna/status/897333107354869760

And also a lengthy issue thread here on the state of things for when they'll allow other dependency versions:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/992